# Laravel Mix ReactJS: how to compile only on file save rather than after every keystroke?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-mix

I would like Laravel Mix to compile my assets ***only*** when I *save* a `.js` file, but *not* in between my keystrokes (on file change).
I am using Laravel Mix 6 in a Larvel 8 project using `npm run watch`

This is a simple React project (react frontend was installed via `laravel/ui`):

`webpack.mix.js`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .react()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What IDE are you using? Maybe make sure your IDE isn't saving after every keystroke? For instance in VSCode,  Settings > Text Editor > Files > Autosave > Off.

Comment: Yes, I was using an online version of VS Code IDE that had autosave on by default. Thank you!